# Display specific object in array of objects PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Supposed i have an array of object of

```
$test
[
    {
         my_string: "ciao",
         my_number: 10
    },
    {
         my_string: "ciao b",
         my_number: 100
    },
    {
         my_string: "ciao c",
         my_number: 100
    },
    {
         my_string: "ciao d",
         my_number: 100
    },
]
```

How can i display the third object "ciao c" `my_string`, `my_number` in the test $array

I tried but it displays all the data i just want only the third object to display

```
function obj($array){
    foreach ($array as $test){
        echo $test->my_string. ' ' .$test->my_number. '<br>';
    }
}
```

the desired output should be

```
ciao c
100
```

Comment: That's not valid PHP.  Please show what you're actually trying to access.

Comment: Please show us proper object, it's mistyped or something I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your object like that,

```
function obj($array){
    echo $array[2]->my_string. ' ' .$array[2]->my_number. '<br>';
}
```

But your definition of object should be proper to achieve this

Comment: Check now, are you getting now

Comment: i tried that before. But im having an error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array then you can access it by index of element. "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" this error says that you try to use stdClass as array (in case when you can try access by index).